# How to listen to real-time updates in Firestore without re-rendering the queried data array on every update

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents I am querying, sorting by 'count' ,and listening to real-time updates on. However, every time any document (e.g. 'count') updates, the entire array of documents re-renders and re-sorts by 'count'. I'd like to listen for updates but avoid re-rendering the array every update.

Here's a simplified version of the request I'm making. 'queriedData' is what I'll loop through in the JSX.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("someCollection")
      .orderBy("count", "desc")
      .onSnapshot(collection => {
        const newArray = [];
        collection.forEach(document => {
          const { name, count } = document.data();
          newArray.push({
            key: document.id,
            name,
            count
          });
        });
        setQueriedData(newArray); // <-- array in the JSX
      });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [queriedData]);
```

I've thought of trying to change how I present the array of queried data, but idk how to loop through queried Firestore data without first putting it into an array like I've done here.

Comment: You're creating a new array each time `queriedData` changes, why not just update the existing one on the state?

Comment: I don't know how to do that within the scope of this problem. I tried setting the array state initially like `setQueriedData([{key: document.id, name, count}])` but that only renders one item and is buggy.

Comment: How about `setQueriedData(arr => [...arr, newArray])` which will append the new array to the current state?

Comment: you can get documentChanges

Answer (score 7):

The `onSnapshot` callback gives you a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). This object does not just contain the documents you requested, but also a [`docChanges` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#doc-changes), which gives you more information about the exact changes.

The documentation on [viewing changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) contains a good example of how to process document changes:

> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
> .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
>     snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
>         if (change.type === "added") {
>             console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
>         }
>         if (change.type === "modified") {
>             console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
>         }
>         if (change.type === "removed") {
>             console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Initially when your callback runs, you'll get `change.type === "added"` for each document, and you'll do the same as you have in your current code. But on subsequent updates, you'll only get events for the actual changes to the collection/query.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to use this. I've integrated it with my code and upon querying, the data is correctly coming up as `change.type === "added"`, but once I modify a document, all other documents, apart from the modified one, disappear from the queried array. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Yes. `docChanges()` shows only the added/changed/removed data, so that you can perform a minimal update to the UI. That's how you can prevent rerendering the entire UI on every change.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this may be obvious but I am unclear about something. I'm considering whether to use this pattern vs. using a cloud function. In my use case, I am listening to an entire collection, when there's an addition, I want to capture it. I noticed that when I first run this listener,  - the console.log prints every document in the collection. Afterwards, only the document that was added. Does this mean that anytime there's a change to the collection, the entire collection is 'read', or does that read of every document only happen upon initialization of the listener?

Comment: Initially the entire collection is read. When there's an update, **only the update is read**, but the listener is invoked again with an entire snapshot of the new state of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the array builds your JSX it changes the props, and when props change it rerender de component.

you could either:

1. have a memo with a boolean that you change only when you want the list to re-render
2. or use a different variable that will be used in your method that "listens" to real-time changes.